# Jquery datatable numeric sort

Tags: php, jquery

I useed the jquery datatable  for table sorting for the following data.

```
        <table width="50%" border="0" id="pls-pitching">
    <tr>
    <td><span>1</span>
    <input name="t" type="text" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>5</span>
    <input name="t" type="text" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><span>2</span>
    <input name="t" type="text" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>3</span>
    <input name="t" type="text" value="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span>10</span>
    <input name="t" type="text" value="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Here i want to sort the text box values as 1,2,3,5,10
I couldn't implement the text box value sorting. So i added the `<span>` tag before the text box like (`<span>10</span>`). Now it sorts the values. But it sort like 1,10,2,3,5

But i need to sort this like the numeric sort.

I used the following javascript command

```
$('#pls-pitching').dataTable();
```

Is there any possibility to implement the text box value sorting ? Please do the needful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own function to do the comparison. [Here is example of how to do it](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/sorting_plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what worked for me,

1.Define the custom type of sort(for numeric values)

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-asc'] = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseInt( x );
    y = parseInt( y );
    return ((x < y || isNaN(y) ) ? -1 : ((x > y || isNaN(x)) ? 1 : 0));
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseInt( x );
    y = parseInt( y );
    return ((x < y || isNaN(x)) ? 1 : ((x > y || isNaN(y) ) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

2.Set the type of sort while initialising datatable,

```
 $(".fooTable").dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
         {"sType" : "num-html" }]
 });
```